# Eclipse Git Error: Error occurred computing diffs

Tags: android, eclipse, git

When trying to commit changes to my `Android` project in `git` in Eclipse Indigo, I get the following error:

> "Error occurred computing diffs. Missing tree " + hex number.

I searched Google for a solution but haven't found one.

- What does this error mean?
- How can I fix it?

I'm beginner level with `git` and intermediate with Eclipse.

Comment: I have managed to make git work from within eclipse only intermittently. I use the github app, or sourcetree on a mac, to manage the repository, and then refresh eclipse, or close eclipse and start again. Eclipse has given me strange results with git so often that I've stopped worrying.

Comment: @emrys57 Thanks. I'll try the github app as you suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question. Maybe this will help someone as I haven't found any other answer on the web about this error.

The error occured when my laptop hard drive was almost full, at approx. 95%. When I restarted the laptop, Windows started a registry repair and moved a set of missing files back into the right directory. I them emptied the laptop hard drive down to 70% full. After this, I could run the commit as expected.

I don't know if the lack of space on the hard drive or an registry error caused the issue but it coincided. So, as advice, if you get this error, make sure to:

- have sufficient space on your hard drive to write to.
- check if you need to run a registry repair.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I ran into the same issue with a different resolution.  My repo is on a local network and the connection had been lost but then re-established and apparently eGit didn't like that.  I restarted eclipse and everything ran fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error today and after reading the answer above I realized I got it because of windows update. Windows installed some updates but I waited with the restart. After restarting my computer it all worked again.

Conclusion: It's most likely registry related.