# How to fix an error in Eclipse when trying to commit code to Bitbucket

Tags: eclipse, bitbucket

I am trying to commit (Team - Commit...) my project in Eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) Build id: 20160218-0600 to Bitbucket and I get the error:

```
Error occurred computing diffs
C:\Users\Glynd\Documents\gitignore_global.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

The file is in this location - date last modified 14/01/2020 type .symlink and size 0 KB.

My last commit to Bitbucket was only two days ago.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue please. I am a novice at this so simple step by step instructions would be appreciated.

Comment: Your Eclipse is pretty old. You are a couple of years and 11 releases behind. Please do not waste time by using outdated software and use Eclipse 2020-06 (4.16) instead.

Comment: Hi Howlger, I have been reticent to upgrade when the current is working (see solution below). Especially with my lack of technical knowledge. I will see if I can have the two running concurrently so I do not loose the ability to keep working while trying to create the new Eclipse version. It is a pity Eclipse does not simply update to the latest version.

Comment: Your Eclipse is also too old to simply update to the latest version. Please do not waste your and our time by using outdated software.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you run into an error message you haven't seen before, search for the error message on the internet (minus any unique or application-specific portions).

When you do, you'll find this: [Eclipse Git Error: Error occurred computing diffs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628531/eclipse-git-error-error-occurred-computing-diffs) .

This may help.

Comment: Thank you David. I did do as you suggested before posting and did not find an appropriate solution. The solution ended up being very simple and spotted by a friend.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file is in the location (date last modified 14/01/2020 type .symlink and size 0 KB) and create an empty .txt file with the same name.